# partticles.js Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties

Tags: javascript, particles.js

When using particles.js I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them

I have tried installing particles.js with npm and have also attempted to use it by bundling the script into my app.js with webpack.   I can confirm that the script exists in my bundle as when I check the sources tab in chrome, I can see the code exists.

I then call particles.js with:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    particlesJS('particle-layer', {
        particles: {
            color: '#fff',
            shape: 'circle', // "circle", "edge" or "triangle"
            opacity: 0.5,
            size: 2,
            size_random: true,
            nb: 200,
            line_linked: {
                enable_auto: true,
                distance: 250,
                color: '#fff',
                opacity: 0.5,
                width: 1,
                condensed_mode: {
                    enable: true,
                    rotateX: 600,
                    rotateY: 600
                }
            },
            anim: {
                enable: true,
                speed: 2
            }
        },
        interactivity: {
            enable: false,
            mouse: {
                distance: 250
            },
            detect_on: 'canvas', // "canvas" or "window"
            mode: 'grab'
        },
        /* Retina Display Support */
        retina_detect: false
    });
}, false );
```

**UPDATE**
As @JamesThorpe suggested the `arguments.callee` is causing the problem, however commenting it out results in all nodes being drawn at 50x50px.  Is there an ES6 alternative for `arguments.callee`?

Comment: It looks like you've already done the right thing by [raising an issue](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/123) for this - it seems particle.js isn't designed to run in strict mode due to it's [usage of `arguments.callee` in one of the functions](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/particles.js#L1421), though it seems it might be there as a utility function, so perhaps it will be straightforward to find an alternative.

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes I have raised an issue, but I thought I would ask again here just in case anybody had ran into this problem before.  From the reading I've done it looks like ES6 implicitly runs in strict mode, but particles.js just doesn't play nice with it.

Comment: @Alex: ES6 (ES2015) only defaults to strict mode in modules. Otherwise, the default is loose.